# How to pass parameters to onsen dialog from script to html

Tags: onsen-ui

I am pretty new to onsen. I have some onsen list item and have a settings button on every list. What I want is on clicking the settings button, I want to pass the parameter from the script page to the html page.I tried the documentation, they din't gave any example. I really couldn't crack it. Thanks in advance. Here is my code!

**CODE**

```js
//Action button click event
            $scope.Settings = function (id) {
                $scope.settings_id = id;
                ons.createDialog('dialog.html').then(function(dialog) {
                    console.log($scope.settings_id);
                    dialog.show();
                });
            }
```

```html
<ons-template id="test.html">
        <ons-page>
                <!--List Start-->
                <ons-list>
                    <ons-list-item class="list-item-container" ng-repeat="item in Items">
                        <ons-row>
                            <ons-col>
                                <div class="name">
                                    {{item.name}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="price">
                                    View <span>{{item.price}}</span> |  Expiring in {{item.validity}} Days
                                </div>
                            </ons-col>
                            <ons-col>
                                <ons-icon ng-click="Settings(item.id)" icon="ion-ios-gear" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                            </ons-col>
                        </ons-row>
                    </ons-list-item>
                </ons-list>
                <!--List End-->
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

<ons-template id="dialog.html">
<ons-dialog var="dialog" cancelable>
    <ons-toolbar inline>
      <div class="center">
        Dialog Title
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div class="dialog-button-group" style="text-align: center">
      <p>
      <ons-button ng-click="Something()" class="button btn-edit"> <i class="ion-ios-compose-outline"></i> Edit</ons-button>
        <ons-button ng-click="SomethingElse()" class="button btn-delete"> <i class="ion-ios-trash-outline"></i> Delete</ons-button>
        <ons-button ng-click="dialog.hide()" class="button btn-close"> <i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i> Close</ons-button>
      </p>
    </div>
</ons-dialog>        
</ons-template>
```

Actually the console is printing the id promptly. I still dont know how to pass that value so that i can redirect to a page according to that id. Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean this (second paragraph)? http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#ShowingDialog

Comment: Thanks. that helps !

Answer (score 0):

The ons.createDialog() method also accepts an options object. One of the parameters, options.parentScope, can be used to pass a scope object that the inner scope of the dialog will inherit from.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope) {
ons.ready(function() {
ons.createDialog('dialog.html', {parentScope: $scope}).then(function(dialog) 
 {
  $scope.dialog = dialog;
});
});

 // This variable will be available in the dialog scope as well.
 $scope.myVariable = 'Hello!';
});
```